# How can I increase the precision of the calculations in this python code

Tags: python, precision

I am trying to reproduce a plot on page 81 of Math Letters Jr. (which is a great recreational math book, by the way). The plot is created using a pair of simple functions that are applied iteratively (i.e. the output of each loop is the input for the following loop). Plotting the output x, y point in each loop should produce a beautiful complex point cloud. However, when I implemented the code below, it gets stuck cycling between 4 identical points after the fiftieth iteration. I assume this is due to rounding due to insufficient precision in my variable definitions. How can I improve on this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 0
y = 0
vecx = []
vecy = []

for i in range(5000):
    x = 1.3 + 0.3*x + 0.6*x*y - 0.6*y - y**2
    y = 0.1 - 0.7*x + 0.5*(x**2) - 0.8*x*y + 0.1*y - 0.6*(y**2)
    vecx.append(x)
    vecy.append(y)
    
plt.plot(vecx, vecy, 'b.')
```

Comment: Class `decimal.Decimal` may help.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Just tried that. Gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module of Python:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

# Set the precision for decimal calculations
getcontext().prec = 50  # You can adjust the precision as needed

x = Decimal('0')
y = Decimal('0')
vecx = []
vecy = []

for i in range(5000):
    x_new = Decimal('1.3') + Decimal('0.3') * x + Decimal('0.6') * x * y - Decimal('0.6') * y - y**2
    y_new = Decimal('0.1') - Decimal('0.7') * x + Decimal('0.5') * (x**2) - Decimal('0.8') * x * y + Decimal('0.1') * y - Decimal('0.6') * (y**2)
    x, y = x_new, y_new
    vecx.append(x)
    vecy.append(y)
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out explicitly that `x, y = x_new, y_new` is the key here. You need to calculate the new value of `y` with the old value of `x` not the updated version.

Comment: True, that seems to be the crux of the issue

Comment: OP here, I agree. I edited my code using x, y = x_new, y_new without changing anything else (i.e. without introducing the Decimal class) and it reproduced the plot in the book perfectly. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this with 100 iterations and its working properly:

```
x = 0
y = 0
vecx = []
vecy = []

for i in range(100):
    new_x = 1.3 + 0.3*x + 0.6*x*y - 0.6*y - y**2
    new_y = 0.1 - 0.7*x + 0.5*(x**2) - 0.8*x*y + 0.1*y - 0.6*(y**2)
    
    x, y = new_x, new_y  # Update x and y for the next iteration        

    vecx.append(x)
    vecy.append(y)

    print('x', x)
    print('y', y)
```

Comment: To be compliant with OP's version, your code ought to append `x` and `y` after updating them for the next iteration

Comment: Ya, thanks for pointing that out. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using Decimal library for precise floating point numbers calculations. `from decimal import Decimal` and provide numbers as a string for example `y = Decimal('1.005')`